# FROM Clause Subquery Add a Column from Another Table

Tags: sql-server

I am having trouble wrapping my head around a subquery in the FROM clause. I have a subquery that I want to add to the FROM clause. I only added the nconst column, then JOIN it to the name_basics table with the column nconst and it does everything but what it should output. Why would that be? It makes no sense that the code should mess up, all I am doing is adding another column, not manipulating the code (as far as I know).

Also, it has to be in the FROM clause for the assignment. I am just looking for clarification. I know how the FROM clause works when linking direct keys for the output column. For this, I don't want to show the nconst value in the output and that is where I am lost.

The output should be the name of everyone in that profession. The NP subquery originally doesn't have nconst values in it.

Here is my code

```
SELECT  primaryName, profession
   FROM (
        SELECT      profession, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL, nconst
        FROM        name_profession
        GROUP BY    profession, nconst
        HAVING      COUNT(*) < 1000             
    ) AS NP
JOIN    
    (
        SELECT      primaryName, nconst
        FROM        name_basics
    ) AS NB
ON      NP.nconst = NB.nconst
ORDER BY primaryName;
```

Comment: Because this is data related - and we can see none, I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). Providing **sample data** and **expected result** will bring about relevant answers with minimal waiting time. Better for you and us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join the table itself

```
SELECT  ??.primaryName, ??.profession, GP.total
FROM (
        SELECT      profession, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL, nconst
        FROM        name_profession
        GROUP BY    profession, nconst
        HAVING      COUNT(*) < 1000             
    ) AS GP
INNER JOIN  name_basics AS NB ON GP.nconst = NB.nconst
ORDER BY primaryName;
```

But please use table aliases in the select and where clauses now - always. Replace the ?? seen above with appropriate table aliases.

If you are joining to a subquery, and you need a specific column from that, you MUST include that column in the select clause of the subquery. i.e. the outer query only has access to the selected columns in that subquery.

If having issues with the join, display more so you can debug:

```
SELECT
    NB.primaryName, GP.profession, GP.nconst, GP.total
FROM name_basics AS NB
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            profession, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL, nconst
        FROM name_profession
        GROUP BY
            profession
          , nconst
        HAVING COUNT(*) < 1000
    ) AS GP
    ON GP.nconst = NB.nconst
ORDER BY
    primaryName;
```

---

> for investigating the impact of `nconst` in the subquery, perhaps this will help:

Please **Compare the results** of this:

```
    SELECT
        profession, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
    FROM name_profession
    GROUP BY
        profession
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 1000
```

and this:

```
    SELECT
        profession, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL, nconst
    FROM name_profession
    GROUP BY
        profession
      , nconst
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 1000
```

Now consider how the second query (using an inner join) will affect work with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    NB.primaryName, NB.nconst
FROM name_basics AS NB
```

Comment: sorry I was having issues with "np" and "nb", way too similar IMO, so I went to "gp" for "group professions" instead

Comment: I've done it like this before and the **nconst in GP** throws it off. It returns the opposite of what it should be. I should only have **3 professions**. It returns everything but those 3. Take **nconst** out and it works. It is a bit confusing

Comment: well, that is "related to data", and I can see none. as you increase the number of columns in the **group by** you will normally increase the rows that it produces. I will add another query as a suggestion. back soon.

Comment: @user10466320 - You need to properly alias your code. As it stands now, you have nconst is the outer select and you've give the optimizer two to choose from, in the FROM clause, and no direction as to which one you want it to use.

Comment: @user10466320 suggest you try a left join to your grouping subquery, I have suggested one above, this should reveal the cause of your difficulty I hope

Comment: @Used_By_Already this code works in reverse of what I needed. This is what I am confused about. How can adding nconst into the subquery make it return all the names for other professions?

Comment: @JasonA.Long I kind of see what you mean. Should the alias matter since I am using the alias for the column name to specify which nconst to use?

Comment: OMG. **ALIAS EVERYTHING, ALWAYS** I already said that. This  should have been handled under the question not under my answer.

Comment: Going back to the real issue: **look at the data**. I cannot do this for you, unless you supply some sample data in the question (do NOT use comments for this).  The purpose of the left join is to help you **look at the data** and then you should understand why.

Comment: @user10466320 - Yes, the aliases matter. Used_By_Already is giving you very solid advise. The forums are littered with broken queries written by people who thought that just because a query executed w/o errors, it was doing what they though it was doing. The fact is, if SQL Server has more than one column available, to choose from, and you don't use aliases, you really don't have a clue which one it's using. (Okay, that last bit may be a stretch... but... if you knew enough about internals to know, you'd already know how important aliases are.)

Comment: I have added some suggestions to my answer. Doubt I can any more here as I cannot see your data.

Comment: @Used_By_Already You did break this down for me and the last examples helped to see exactly what is happening between everything. I think I am able to troubleshoot this correctly, thank you!